# How can you use multiprocessing in Python to divide up iterating through a dictionary?

Tags: python, queue, multiprocessing, pool

I have a project to read millions of lines of input and then to run calculations on a very large dictionary.  I have implemented Pool/Queue techniques on some of the IO parts of the program earlier.  However, is there a way to use multiprocessing to divide up the standard:

for i in xdictionary.iteritems():

Thanks!

Comment: try using [`concurrent.futures`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/concurrent.futures.html)

Answer (score 3):

You could use `imap`:

```
import multiprocessing
import os

def f(key_value):
    print "pid={}, key={}, value={}".format(os.getpid(), *key_value)

pool = multiprocessing.Pool(2)
for _ in pool.imap(f, {1:2, 3:4, 5:6, 7:8}.iteritems()):
    pass
```

Out:

```
pid=1689, key=1, value=2
pid=1689, key=3, value=4
pid=1689, key=5, value=6
pid=1690, key=7, value=8
```

Answer (score 0):

```
import multiprocessing as mp

def main():
    numProcs = mp.cpu_count()
    qIn, qOut = [mp.Queue() for _ in xrange(2)]
    procs = [mp.process(target=dowork, args=(qIn, qOut)) for _ in range(numProcs)]
    for p in procs: p.start()

    for k,v in xdict.iteritems():
        qIn.put((k,v))
    for _ in xrange(numProcs):
        qIn.put(None)

    done = 0
    while done < numProcs:
        res = qOut.get()
        if res is None:
            done += 1
            continue
        k,v,ans = res
        print "processing", k, v, "gives:", ans

    for p in procs: p.terminate()

def dowork(qIn, qOut):
    for k,v in iter(qIn.get, None):
        answer = doStuff(k,v)
        qOut.put((k,v,answer))
    qOut.put(None)
```